# SIR model using fsolve and Euler 3BDF

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

Hi i've been asked to solve SIR model using fsolve command in MATLAB, and Euler 3 point backward. I'm really confused on how to proceed, please help.  This is what i have so far. I created a function for 3BDF scheme but i'm not sure how to proceed with fsolve and solve the system of nonlinear ODEs. The SIR model is shown as [image] and 3BDF scheme is formulated as [image]

```
clc
clear all 
gamma=1/7;
beta=1/3;
ode1= @(R,S,I) -(beta*I*S)/(S+I+R);
ode2= @(R,S,I) (beta*I*S)/(S+I+R)-I*gamma;
ode3= @(I) gamma*I;
f(t,[S,I,R]) = [-(beta*I*S)/(S+I+R); (beta*I*S)/(S+I+R)-I*gamma; gamma*I];
R0=0;
I0=10;
S0=8e6;

odes={ode1;ode2;ode3}
fun = @root2d;
x0 = [0,0];
x = fsolve(fun,x0)



function [xs,yb] = ThreePointBDF(f,x0, xmax, h, y0)
% This function should return the numerical solution of y at x = xmax.
% (It should not return the entire time history of y.)
% TO BE COMPLETED


xs=x0:h:xmax;
y=zeros(1,length(xs));
y(1)=y0;
yb(1)=y0+f(x0,y0)*h;


for i=1:length(xs)-1

R =R0;


y1(i+1,:) = fsolve(@(u) u-2*h/3*f(t(i+1),u) - R, y1(i-1,:)+2*h*F(i,:))


S = S0;
y2(i+1,:) = fsolve(@(u) u-2*h/3*f(t(i+1),u) - S, y2(i-1,:)+2*h*F(i,:))


I= I0;
y3(i+1,:) = fsolve(@(u) u-2*h/3*f(t(i+1),u) - I, y3(i-1,:)+2*h*F(i,:))



end


end
```

Comment: Note that this is the order 2 BDF formula. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3051078/115115 for using fsolve to implement an implicit method.

Comment: Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53910201/3088138) of using fsolve to implement an implicit method. Note that in general using fsolve to compute an implicit step is wasteful, especially if/as the approximate Jacobian is not reused.

Answer (score 1):

You have an implicit equation

```
y(i+1) - 2*h/3*f(t(i+1),y(i+1)) = G = (4*y(i) - y(i-1))/3
```

where the right-side term `G` is constant in the call to `fsolve`, that is, during the solution of the implicit step equation.

*Note that this is for the vector valued system `y'(t)=f(t,y(t))` where*

```
f(t,[S,I,R]) = [-(beta*I*S)/(S+I+R); (beta*I*S)/(S+I+R)-I*gamma; gamma*I];
```

To solve this write

```
G = (4*y(i,:) - y(i-1,:))/3
y(i+1,:) = fsolve(@(u) u-2*h/3*f(t(i+1),u) - G, y(i-1,:)+2*h*F(i,:))
```

where a midpoint step is used to get an order 2 approximation as initial guess, `F(i,:)=f(t(i),y(i,:))`. Add solver options for error tolerances as necessary, you want the error in the implicit equation smaller than the truncation error `O(h^3)` of the step. One can also keep only a short array of function values, then one has to be careful for the correspondence of the position in the short array to the time index.

Using all that and a reference solution by a higher order standard solver produces the following error graphs for the components

[image]

where one can see that the first order error of the constant first step results in a first order global error, while with a second order error in the first step using the Euler method results in a clear second order global error.

---

Implement the method in general terms

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def BDF2(f,t,y0,y1):
    N, h = len(t)-1, t[1]-t[0];
    y = (N+1)*[np.asarray(y0)];
    y[1] = y1;
    for i in range(1,N):
        t1, G = t[i+1], (4*y[i]-y[i-1])/3
        y[i+1] = fsolve(lambda u: u-2*h/3*f(t1,u)-G, y[i-1]+2*h*f(t[i],y[i]), xtol=1e-3*h**3)
    return np.vstack(y)
```

Set up the model to be solved

```
gamma=1/7;
beta=1/3;
print beta, gamma
y0 = np.array([8e6, 10, 0])
P = sum(y0); y0 = y0/P
def f(t,y): S,I,R = y; trns = beta*S*I/(S+I+R); recv=gamma*I; return np.array([-trns, trns-recv, recv])
```

Compute a reference solution and method solutions for the two initialization variants

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint

tg = np.linspace(0,120,25*128)
yg = odeint(f,y0,tg,atol=1e-12, rtol=1e-14, tfirst=True)

M = 16; # 8,4
t = tg[::M];
h = t[1]-t[0];
y1 = BDF2(f,t,y0,y0)
e1 = y1-yg[::M]
y2 = BDF2(f,t,y0,y0+h*f(0,y0))
e2 = y2-yg[::M]
```

Plot the errors, computation as above, but embedded in the plot commands, could be separated in principle by first computing a list of solutions

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,2,figsize=(12,6))
for M in [16, 8, 4]:
    t = tg[::M];
    h = t[1]-t[0];
    y = BDF2(f,t,y0,y0)
    e = (y-yg[::M])
    for k in range(3): ax[k,0].plot(t,e[:,k],'-o', ms=1, lw=0.5, label = "h=%.3f"%h)
    y = BDF2(f,t,y0,y0+h*f(0,y0))
    e = (y-yg[::M])
    for k in range(3): ax[k,1].plot(t,e[:,k],'-o', ms=1, lw=0.5, label = "h=%.3f"%h)
for k in range(3): 
    for j in range(2): ax[k,j].set_ylabel(["$e_S$","$e_I$","$e_R$"][k]); ax[k,j].legend(); ax[k,j].grid()
ax[0,0].set_title("Errors: first step constant");
ax[0,1].set_title("Errors: first step Euler")
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Im not sure what you did by equating y(i+1) - 2*h/3*f(t(i+1),y(i+1)) = R and also where doeas t come from and how would i implement the other 2 equations

Comment: Thank you very much, so i would need to creat F=[f1,f2,f3] and also since initail conditions are given in the problem why would i have to calculate it? also the function handle u corresponds to what exactly?

Comment: `u` stands for the unknown value of `y(i+1,:)`, the first argument of `fsolve` has to be the function that you are trying to find a root of. You get `y(1,:)` from the initial condition, you need to compute `y(2,:)` via other means to at least second order, then you can start to apply the BDF method from `y(3,:)` on.

Comment: Thanks again, I wrote the following and implemented your suggestions however it doesnt seem to work, I tried to debug but havent been able to figure it out.

Comment: Also I ve been asked to use one time  y(i+1)=y0+h*f(x0,y0) and another time IC as y(i+1)

Comment: Setting `y(2)=y(1)` will definitely destroy the order of the method. Using an Euler step for the first time will ensure second order, however it will also increase the coefficient of the leading error term.

Comment: You should be able to recognize what is valid Matlab code and what is some ASCII approximation of a mathematical formula. Mixing both will not work.

Comment: Thanks, i tried runnung the posted code in python and i recieved an error that odeint is unrecognized. Also how would convert the BDF2 function to BDF3.

Comment: odeint needs to be imported from scipy.integrate. I have that as standard import, so sometimes forget it in the posted code. Also numpy as np and pyplot as plt.

Comment: thanks that helped, could please also add the visualization part as im not familiar with numpy.

Comment: Lutz,Thank you for your help, i have another problem that id appriciate your help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584719/central-difference-a-matrix