# central difference A matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

Hi im trying to code the following coefiicient matrix A in a for loop in Matlab. `N` is the total number of elements. And `i` and `j` are obtained from `k`. Could someone help me please code the A matrix correctly for any `N` value. The `A` and `b` are shown[image]

```
for k = 1:N
    A(k,k) = 4; % the diagonal element, corresponding to Tij, is always 4
    %     In the following, we look at the four neighbours of (i,j) that are
    %     involved in the 5-point formula
    i = mod(k-1,nx)+1;
    j = (k-i)/nx+1; %get (i,j) from k
    %boundary condtion
    if i == 1
        b(k,1) = Tl;

    elseif i == nx
        b(k,1) = Tr;

    elseif j == 1
        b(k,1) = Tb;
    elseif j == ny
        b(k,1) = Tt;
    end
    %A matrix construction
    if i>1 && j>1
        if i == j
            A(j-1,i) = -1;
            A(j,i+1) =- 1;
            A(j,i-1) = -1;
            A(j+1,i) = -1;

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: this example is not reproducible. What are `nx` and `ny`, `Tl`, `Tt`, `Tb`... and how does this coding meets the posted image of a matrix?

Comment: the posted image is an example of how an A matrix would look like.

Comment: You should better explain what your code means. The image is an example of the A matrix. What are the elements T_(i,j) ? If you do not want to use Tij on the A matix, then you should better explain how you want to create this pentadiagonal matrix.

Comment: sorry for poor explanation, A is coefficient of T